# How to solve this polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials

$(3x-1)^4=a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$

Value required to be found :-  $a_4+3a_3+9a_2+27a_1+81a_0$

I can find the value of $a_4+a_3+a_2+a_1+a_0$.Then I don't know how to continue.Please help.

Comment: Can't you just expand it?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain-Method looks dull...:-)

Comment: Sure, but I guess you would be faster by doing so than typing the question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: 
try putting $x=\frac 13$

Comment: Nice @davidquinn. Your answers are always very intuitive and simple.

Comment: @Shailesh thanks very much! The length of my answers is usually in proportion to my skill and patience with Mathjax

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)/the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) you can easily expand $(3x-1)^4$ and determine $a_0,\dots,a_4$.